# Login using class C# in main form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, class, authentication

I make some form first form for login and the second is the main form but I want to connect the user name that enters in the login form to be shown in the main form and another form by using the class in sample way cause I'm weak in classes. All I want is like the session in .net.

I'm a beginner in C# so I'd appreciate your comprehension and beginner-like answers. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem with your code.

Comment: I agree with @Nino however, with more information this question could be fleshed out. Try screenshots, rough paint drawings, really minimal code from anything you have. Some of my first ever questions I asked a question and included a screenshot of the UI and my desired result and that can be acceptable if you don't know very much about coding.